# JSCONObject.getString( "list" ) now returning org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["list"] not a string

Tags: java, json

If had the following code working perfectly for years.  All of a sudden when it runs I get the error message in the title of the post.

responseContactList is returned from an api call.  The resulting tempStr is contains the following JSON:
{
  "list": {
    "access_level": "readonly",
    "address": "9997-dlsrir-b8aky4@mg.lmsnet.com",
    "created_at": "Thu, 10 Jan 2019 15:20:35 -0000",
    "description": "",
    "members_count": 1,
    "name": "123 N. MICHIGAN AVENUE CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION"
  }
}

I validated the JSON is good.  When I step through the debugger and watch the method getString ( see below ) the program is getting a JSONObject instead of a String.  Any idea why this would happen and how to correct it?  This is what shows up as the object value after the .get() call:

{"access_level":"readonly","address":"9997-dlsrir-b8aky4@mg.lmsnet.com","name":"123 N. MICHIGAN AVENUE CONDOMINIUM ASSOCIATION","created_at":"Thu, 10 Jan 2019 15:20:35 -0000","description":"","members_count":1}

```
public MailingList( ClientResponse responseContactList )
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println( "Begin MailingList Constructor!" );
            String tempStr = responseContactList.getEntity(String.class);
            JSONObject aJSONObject = new JSONObject( tempStr );
            aJSONObject = new JSONObject( aJSONObject.getString( "list" ) );
            createdAt = aJSONObject.getString( "created_at" );
            address = aJSONObject.getString( "address" );
            membersCount = Long.parseLong( aJSONObject.getString( "members_count" ) );
            description = aJSONObject.getString( "description" );
            name = aJSONObject.getString( "name" );

        } catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            isValid = false;
        }
        isValid = true;
        System.out.println( "End MailingList Constructor!" );
    }


   /**
     * Get the string associated with a key.
     *
     * @param key
     *            A key string.
     * @return A string which is the value.
     * @throws JSONException
     *             if there is no string value for the key.
     */
    public String getString(String key) throws JSONException {
        Object object = this.get(key);
        if (object instanceof String) {
            return (String) object;
        }
        throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + quote(key) + "] not a string.");
    }
```

Comment: The object that is returned is a JSONObject, not a String. If that started occurring recently, the API changed.

Comment: I thought that as well but my production code still runs fine.  It's almost as if the org.json code was changed.  Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this change make in May 2011 is the likely cause of why there is different behaviour.

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/commit/f4cb14728f13629972a0ea76bb3dc0705a735fa8

Look at line 634.  The toString method used to look like this which would have given you the correct results:

```
 Object object = get(key);
 return object == NULL ? null : object.toString();
```

You must have had JSON libraries earlier than 2011 before and recently updated to a newer version

In order to use the latest libraries, try changing

```
 aJSONObject = new JSONObject( aJSONObject.getString( "list" ) );
```

to

```
 aJSONObject = aJSONObject.getJSONObject( "list" );
```

Comment: I restored the jar file from my backup and it works fine.  Strange it's dated 03/2013 though.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Any thoughts on how to correct this using the updated code?

Comment: instead of  `aJSONObject = new JSONObject( aJSONObject.getString( "list" ) );` try `aJSONObject = aJSONObject.getJSONObject( "list" );`

Comment: I did that and it returns { "empty:false" }

Comment: can you try `aJSONObject = new JSONObject( aJSONObject.get( "list" ).toString() );`

Answer (score 0):

I think `aJSONObject.getJSONObject( "list" )` as a nested object because regarding you json it is not array. If it is a list then the brackets **[ ]** should be square. `aJSONObject.getJSONArray("list")`.

Comment: when I call getJSONOjbect( "list" ) it returns { "empty:false" }
when I call getJSONArray( "list" ) it says it's not an array just like getString isn't a string.

is it possible the org.json code changed recently?